# How do I make R packages portable for a shiny application

Tags: r, package, portability

I have recently created a shiny application project with R studio, with sub-directories for inputs, outputs, packages and code. At the beginning of the code, I do `.libPaths(myProject\packages)` and then, proceed with the code, which reads and writes packages from that folder. It seem to me to be very intuitive to do this, because I need not disturb the native package installations, and I have all the packages required in a single folder. My question is whether this folder is portable. That is, if I take this folder as it is and put it in a different directory or a different system with their own native R installation, and just point to this folder as library path, will it work without issues? I have already read the solution with R-Portable, but I do not wish to use that if I can help it, because that would mean just using up more space than required if I work with multiple projects.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, it sounds to me you're trying to re-invent something that packages like `packrat` and `checkpoint` are already providing. Have you had a look at those packages? Could you provide more details as to why their functionality does not meet your requirements. I'm asking because it may help us better understand what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It really depends. If the packages you intend to install are written purely in R (there isn't any part written in C,C++ or Fortran), they might work without problems. However, I suggest to just distribute the packages and make the installation when you open the app for the first time (you just have to implement a check that verifies if packages are installed and if they are not, you install them).

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I am not familiar with the packages you mentioned. I shall check them now. The specific packages I am using for my application are tidyverse, gridExtra, reshape2, shiny, shinydashboard and extrafont. I am playing around with the possibility of building a standalone R application, with only one prerequisite, that is, a native R installation. I might try to build an actual executable later on with C# integration, but that's the next step. Thank you!

Comment: @nicola, that is a good idea. I had the install.packages() commands commented out, but perhaps I can try with that check implementation. Thank you!